# App.Config returns null

Tags: c#

I have a class library project in which I want to load configuration settings.

Here is the app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="editMode" value="2" />
    <add key="fileType" value="0" />
    <add key="Editor" value="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015\Photoshop.exe" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is the code inside of the main program.

```
string savedEditor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Editor"];
MessageBox.Show(savedEditor);
string savededitMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["editMode"];
MessageBox.Show(savededitMode);                
string savedfileType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileType"];
MessageBox.Show(savedfileType);
```

It compiles OK and the `*.dll.config` file is created.  However, it returns null for the values of the three keys.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: While your library may output an app.config file, it's not what is used when you import that library in another program. I would guess that copying those application settings into the importing application's app.config (or copying the config and renaming it if none exists) will solve your problem.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper using directive: `using System.Configuration;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm just putting my comment as an answer since it's most likely the source of problem.

While your class library project (the thing which builds the dll) may output a config, it is not what is used when importing that class in other projects. The app.config which is used is the one which correlates to the app which is being invoked. Since you most likely do not have these values in that file, attempts to retrieve them from the AppSettings dictionary return `null`. To resolve the problem either copy the items below into your main applications `appSettings` section of it's app.config or create an app.config with those settings if none exists.

```
<add key="editMode" value="2" />
<add key="fileType" value="0" />
<add key="Editor" value="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015\Photoshop.exe" />
```

Comment: Still no luck.  I created a new app.config file for the second file (just copied the same key-values and used the same code to import the configuration settings.  Same thing--null.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above said, the config file that will be used is for the executable calling / referencing the dll.

So if I have an executable called "MyProgram.exe" and your dll is named "MyFirst.dll", then "MyProgram.exe", "MyFirst.dll" and "MyProgram.exe.config" have to be in the same directory. The "MyProgram.exe.config" file needs to have the configuration values that you're trying to retrieve from the config file.

Does that make sense?